# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', while using django-cors-headers

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I am using django-cors-headers to overcome cors issues in python django. But I am getting.

> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. while trying to access using angularjs from http://localhost:8000

here is my settings for CORS that I am using.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + ['corsheaders']

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES + ['corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware']

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER = True


CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
        'x-requested-with',
        'content-type',
        'accept',
        'origin',
        'authorization',
        'x-csrftoken',
        'accept-encoding'
    )

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
        'GET',
        'POST',
        'PUT',
        'PATCH',
        'DELETE',
        'OPTIONS'
    )
```

if anyone has resolved this issue please let me know.

Comment: See https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers/issues/97

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
)
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True #for testing.
```

Look `CorsMiddleware` is on top of `CommonMiddleware`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have done this but this has not resolved my problem, I am still getting the above error `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *',`

Answer (score 0):

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
```

change allow all to false